# How to get values of dynamically generated input fields from jQuery into an JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to fetch the data from a form and posting it to server in JSON format. I am facing problem that values of dynamically generated input fields are not getting fetched, only the value of fields that are static and defined in HTML page is getting fetched.

Below is my HTML code of form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="product-form"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Category</label>
            <div class="dropdown col-sm-2">
                <select class="form-control" id="categories" onchange="displaySub()">
                    <option value="-1">-- Select Category --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="category">Sub-category</label>
            <div class="dropdown col-sm-2">
                <select class="form-control" id="sub-categories" name="category" onchange="displayFields()">
                    <option value="-1">-- Select Sub-category --</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

jQuery code that is generating dynamic input fields

```
function displayFields(){
var cat_dropdown = document.getElementById("sub-categories");
var cat_selected = cat_dropdown.options[cat_dropdown.selectedIndex].text;
for(d of sub_cat){
    if(d.text == cat_selected){
        for(e of d.fields){
            $("#product-form").append(`
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="${e.field}" name="${e.field}">${e.field}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="${e.field}" placeholder="Enter ${e.field}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            `)
        }
        $("#product-form").append(`
            <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id="add-product">Add Product</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `)
    }    
}
```

}

JS code for form submission

```
$("#product-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var data = form.serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/products',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(getFormData(data)),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log("DATA POSTED SUCCESSFULLY"+data);
                },
                error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                    console.log( errorThrown );
                }
    });
});


function getFormData(data) {
   var unindexed_array = data;
   var indexed_array = {};

   $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i) {
    indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
   });

   return indexed_array;
}
```

Now, whenever I submit form only the **category** field is fetched. I want all the field values that are generated dynamically.

Comment: Your added `<input>` fields do not have a "name" attribute, and so they'll be ignored by the `.serializeArray()` method.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. I did a very silly mistake. Instead of giving name attribute to `<input>` field, I gave it to `<label>` field. Now it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved. I gave `name` attribute to label instead of giving it to `input` field getting generated dynamically.

Previous code

```
$("#product-form").append(`
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="${e.field}" name="${e.field}">${e.field}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="${e.field}" placeholder="Enter ${e.field}">
                </div>
            </div>
        `)
```

Rectified Code

```
$("#product-form").append(`
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="${e.field}">${e.field}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="${e.field}" name="${e.field}" placeholder="Enter ${e.field}">
                </div>
            </div>
        `)
```